# Definition of finite in set theory

Tags: set-theory, nonstandard-models

The usual definition of a finite number $n$ in the ZFC set theory is $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is equivalent to "$n$ is 0 or a successor ordinal, and so are all its elements". But this is not obviously equivalent to the intuition of a finite number, which would rather be a group of sticks that one can draw on a paper or a wall. And by the compactness theorem, we can consistently add a new constant symbol $c$ to ZFC, together with the axioms $c\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0 < c, 1 < c, 2 < c, ...$ We call numbers such as $c$ non standard.

I am particularly interested in proving the termination in finite time of certain algorithms or computer programs. And I am now concerned with the following type of reasoning : assume by contradiction that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the program runs for more than $n$ steps, and derive a contradiction. Conclude that there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such as the program terminates in less than $n$ steps. What if this number $n$ was non standard ? It would prove nothing regarding the intended meaning of termination of a program.

Is there a meta-theoretical property of ZFC, telling that every definable $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is standard ? Or telling that the proved existing $n$ above is standard ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. But you might be interested in [this](http://jdh.hamkins.org/every-function-can-be-computable/) blog post by Joel David Hamkins. In it he does exactly what you're describing, and shows that _every_ function is computable in some nonstandard model of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks, this blog is interesting indeed. Question updated.

Comment: We say that a model of ZF is an $\omega$-model if it has only standard natural numbers.

Comment: In a nutshell, ZFC is your basis, your foundation. Working inside a model of ZFC whatever is considered finite there is finite. Working externally to a model of ZFC, the definition of finite is that of the meta-universe, and you can treat the model as any other model of a theory of arithmetic, from RA to PRA to PA.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Then to prove that my algorithms terminate, it seems I need more than an $n\in\mathbb{N}$, rather some sort of computable number or explicit value SSSS...S0 that bounds the number of execution steps. Can ZFC do that ?